# Nothing happened when call function remove layer on leaflet

Tags: javascript, php, leaflet, geojson

I'm tryng to call function for clear layer. But nothing happened,
using this

```
<li class="list-group-item">
      Remove All
      <div class="material-switch pull-right">
        <input id="removeAll" name="someSwitchOption001" type="checkbox" />
        <label for="removeAll" class="label-success"></label>
      </div>
    </li>
```

And this my script

```
    var map = new L.Map('map', {zoom: 8, center: new L.latLng([-2.9365327,  104.4950964]) });


  map.addLayer(new L.TileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png')); //base layer
  <?php foreach ($map_link->result_array() as $i) :?>


    var <?= $i['maplink_var']; ?> = new L.GeoJSON(<?= $i['maplink_var']; ?>, {
      style: function(feature) {
        return {color: feature.properties.color };
      },
      onEachFeature: function(feature, marker) {
       const p = feature.properties;
       p.title = 'p.Name';

       marker.on('click', function (e) {

         var idlink="<?php echo $i['maplink_var']; ?>";
         var aab=feature.properties.ID;
         var numlat =  e.latlng.lat;
         var nlat = numlat.toFixed(3);
         var numlng = e.latlng.lng;
         var nlng = numlng.toFixed(3);

         marker.bindPopup('<td>'+feature.properties.Name+'</td><td>'+ nlat  +'</td><td>'+ nlng +'</td>');
       });

     }
   });
    function removeAllMarkers(){
      markers.clearLayers();
    }

    document.querySelector('removeAll').onclick=function(){removeAllMarkers()};
    map.addLayer(<?= $i['maplink_var']; ?>);

  <?php endforeach; ?>
```

is there an error in calling the Function ID? because there is no notification of an error, it's just that when I click nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

Should have been `document.querySelector('#removeAll')` (note the hash sign #) to select an id.

You do not specify what `markers` is (might be a typo).

Furthermore, with `onclick` you can attach only 1 callback, so if you do it within your foreach loop, only the last one will be called.

You would probably better use an intermediary Layer Group into which adding your built GeoJSON layers, instead of adding them to the map directly.